# basic jquery formatting json request for freebase query

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, jsonp

I'm trying to work with the freebase API but am hitting a snag with the basic formatting for the query I want to build...

The commented out query below works fine... but not my attempt above.  I'm sure the solution is simple but I haven't been able to work it out.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread",
    //url: "https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        query: [{
                "limit": 8,
                "name": null,
                "name~=": request.term+"*" 
                }]
        //query: '[{"name":null,"name~=":"ambrose*","limit":8}]'
    },
    success: function( data ) {
        response( $.map( data.result, function( item ) {
            return {
                label: item.name,
                value: item.name
            }
        }));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commented line value is string(between `' '`):

```
//query: '[{"name":null,"name~=":"ambrose*","limit":8}]'
```

and here we have array:

```
query: [{
   "limit": 8,
   "name": null,
   "name~=": request.term+"*" 
}]
```

change to:

```
query: '[{"limit": 8,"name": null,"name~=": "'+request.term+'*"}]'
```

and now should work

UPDATE:

convert json to string:

```
JSON.stringify([{
    "limit": 8,
    "name": null,
    "name~=": request.term+"*"
}])
```

Comment: That works perfectly, but I also plan to make it a lot longer than that...  Is there a way I could keep it easy to read and not on a single line?